# Questions about using THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry

Tags: three.js

is there anyone familiar with THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry?

The model data I have is only vertices and faces (triangle indices), 
while the same atom model will apply to many instances in the view. 
However, due to shortness of document, I just can't figure out how to do it.

I guess / expect something like this:

```
var geo = new THREE.Geometry();
foreach(vertex) geo.vertices.push(vertex);
foreach(face) geo.faces.push(face);
geo.computeNormals();
var buffer = new THREE.BufferedGeometry().fromGeometry(geo);
geo.dispose();
var instances = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();
copy buffer.positions to instances;
copy buffer.normals to instances;
copy buffer.index to instances;
copy buffer.colors to instances;
var offset = new THREE. InstancedBufferAttribute (...);
foreach(instance new location) offset.setXYZ(...);
instances.addAttribute('offset', offset);

var mat = new THREE.someMaterial (...);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(instances, mat);
scene.add(mesh);
```

will it work?

anyway, could I also ask what the difference is between geometry.colors and material?
In my previous experiences, I always use material to make a mesh, 
but this is the first time that I notice there is a color attribute of each vertex. 
If both vertex color and material with different color settings had been applied, what would happened then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a long while, I figured it out this works greate:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var geometry_array = [...];
geometry_array.forEach(function(geo)) {
   geometry.merge(geo);
}//next

var buf = new THREE.BufferedGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry);
geometry.dispose();
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(buf, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally. Just copy multiple BufferGeometry will work pretty well.